# Serializer for mongo models excluding specific related class type

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Consider the following models:

```
class Line(Document):
    name = StringField()

class Root(Document):
    name = StringField()
    children = ListField(fields=ReferenceField('RootContent'))

class RootContent(Document):
    meta = { 'allow_inheritance': True }

class Directory(RootContent):
    name = StringField()
    children = ListField(fields=ReferenceField('RootContent'))

class File(RootContent):
    name = StringField()
    children = ListField(fields=ReferenceField('Line'))
```

I need a serializer using django-rest-framework-mongoengine that may provide me with all roots having all directories and files, but not lines. I may set a fairly large value of "depth". How do I write a serializer that does it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up doing something like the following:

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers as mongo_serializers

class ChildField(mongo_serializers.serializers.Serializer):
    def to_native(self, value):
        return self.parent.to_native(value)

class TreeSerializer(mongo_serializers.MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    name = mongo_serializers.fields.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_name')
    children = ChildField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Root

    def get_name(self, obj):
        """Mainly in to nullify children of 
        object"""
        if isinstance(obj, File):
            obj.children = []
        return obj.name
```